# Is there a C++ standard for thread-safe class variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, thread-safety

Is there a C++ language feature for thread-safe class member variables? A quick search or two revealed nothing, but I thought it was pretty simple and came up with this solution.

```
template <class T>
class ThreadSafeVar
{
private:
    T safeVar;
    std::mutex accessMutex;

public:
    ThreadSafeVar(T initialValue) { safeVar = initialValue; }
    ThreadSafeVar<T>& operator=(const T &source) { set(source); return *this; }
    ThreadSafeVar<T>& operator=(ThreadSafeVar<T> &source) { set(source.get()); return *this; };

    void set(T newValue)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(accessMutex);
        safeVar = newValue;
    };

    T const get(void)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(accessMutex);
        return safeVar;
    };
};
```

Is there anything wrong with this solution (possible deadlocks, etc.)? Does C++ already have a method for doing this?

Comment: For TriviallyCopyable types, std::atomic<T> provides set, get, and exchange methods.

Comment: Why use a mutex? A TCryticalSection is not sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and [std::memory_order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

The following is an example you can try with `g++ -std=c++ atomic_example.cpp`.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class ThreadSafeVar {
 public:
  ThreadSafeVar() { var_.store(0, std::memory_order::memory_order_relaxed); }
  ~ThreadSafeVar() {}

  void Add() { var_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire); }

  long Get() { return var_.load(std::memory_order_acquire); }

 private:
  std::atomic<long> var_;
};

void Foo(ThreadSafeVar& var) {
  long i = 0;
  while (i++ < (1l << 20)) {
    var.Add();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ThreadSafeVar var;
  std::thread thr1 = std::thread(Foo, std::ref(var));
  std::thread thr2 = std::thread(Foo, std::ref(var));
  thr1.join();
  thr2.join();
  std::cout << "var = " << var.Get() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. For the the trivially copiable types there is std::atomic.